# "Conflicts Found" Error Message When Using Mergin Maps and QGIS

Tags: qgis, mergin-maps

I have a project in QGIS that I have synced it to Mergin Maps and it has worked in the past but now I got the error message "Conflicts found".

I am curious if anyone else has had this same error or if they know what exactly causes it?

[image]

Answer (score 2):

The error suggests that that there is a conflict in synchronisation of your geojson file crib_point_locations.

Conflicts happen when two users edit some files in a shared project at once. When you store data in GeoPackage Mergin Maps uses library geodiff to merge the concurrent edits in most cases, but for other file types the conflict always happen.

You can read more about conflict files and synchronisation in the [documentation](https://merginmaps.com/docs/manage/synchronisation/#conflict-files)